# Codenameone designer doesnt launch from eclipse

Tags: codenameone

IDE: Eclipse Luna
Desktop OS: Windows Server 2008  R2 Enterprise
Simulator : NA/default
Device: NA/default
Java: jdk1.8.0_40

Good afternoon everybody. I am a newbie and downloaded codenameone for the first time as a plugin in Eclipse IDE. The install went well, and I launched a new project, with Native theme and Hello World template. The project got created fine however, when I try to launch theme.res nothing happens. I dont see any errors or any signs of codenameone designer launching.

I searched through the forums and couldnt find anyone with similar problem.

What I have done to resolve (unsuccessfully):

1. Tried creating other projects with different themes and templates.
2. Tried uninstalling codenameone plugin and reinstalling it
3. Tried doing everything in a new workspace.
4. I have tried launching the designer jar from command line and that works:
   java -Xmx256m -jar ~/.codenameone/designer_1.jar (This works)
5. I have double checked and eclipse is running the same version of JVM as commandline.

Nothing I do in eclipse has worked.

Could you please guide ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the VM Eclipse is using to JDK 1.7 this also means the VM used to launch eclipse itself in the `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you for your response.  This is how my eclipse.ini looks it doesnt have a JAVA setting:

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: Thanks - after just updating the Java to 1.7 (changing the JAVA_HOME variables) worked for me. Thank you so much!!